# SQL - Matching only the values in IN clause (not less or more)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, where-clause, having-clause

I am having the following ManyToMany table **TEAM_USERS** with the below data:

```
TEAM_ID     USER_ID
1           10
1           3
1           4
1           11
12          10
12          3
12          4
11          3
11          4
18          10
18          7
18          4
18          11
```

So, I want to get the TEAM_ID that is having only two user with the USER_ID IN (3, 4), in this case it's team 11. But I am getting team 1, 11, and 12. And I want only team 11.

I did the following code but I am not getting the expected results

```
SELECT  team_id
FROM    team_users 
WHERE   user_profile_id IN (3 , 4)
GROUP   BY team_id
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT user_profile_id) = 2;
```

the results for this query is:

```
TEAM_ID
1
11
12
```

So, please any help would be really appreciated.

===============
EDIT: The list is unique, and there is no duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the WHERE-condition into *conditional aggregation*.

As long as the combination team_id/user_profile_id is unique:

```
select team_id
from team_users 
group by team_id
-- exactly those two and no other
having sum(case when user_profile_id in (3, 4) then 1 else -1 end) = 2
```

Comment: Yes, the combination is unique, that's why I want to get the team_id to prevent the duplicate. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `where` clause filters out rows whose `user_profile_id` is other than `3` or `4` before you get a chance to consider them. You could move the logic to the `having` clause instead, like:

```
select team_id
from team_users 
group by team_id
having  
    sum(case when user_profile_id in (3, 4) then 1 else 0 end) = 2
    and sum(case when user_profile not in (3, 4) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This assumes that `(team_id, user_profile_id)` tuples are unique in your data, as shown in your sample data.

Comment: There is no duplicates, and your solution worked fine. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Move all the filtering to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT team_id
FROM team_users 
GROUP BY team_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_profile_id IN (3 , 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2;
```

This checks that there are two members and they are the two specified members.  Also, this assumes there are no duplicates, which seems reasonable.

You can also express this using `LISTAGG()` assuming the lists are not too big:

```
SELECT team_id
FROM team_users 
GROUP BY team_id
HAVING LISTAGG(user_profile_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_profile_id) = '3,4';
```

Comment: I would go one step further and do `COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN user_profile_id IN (3 , 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` - No reason to calculate the number of items in the `in` clause....

Comment: @ZoharPeled: This will also return a team where only 3 *or* 4 exist

Comment: @Gordon thanks for knowledge sharing, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply AND condition for where clause to just get results for `team_id = 11`

```
SELECT  team_id
FROM    team_users 
WHERE   user_profile_id IN (3 , 4) AND team_id = 11
GROUP   BY team_id
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT user_profile_id) = 2;
```

I don't have similar test db setup so you might wanna run and check it

Comment: team_id = 11 , is what I am trying to get, so I am already doesn't have the team_id to pass it as a parameter